# Use with NPM package bootstrap-markdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, markdown

I am currently using the NPM package bootstrap-markdown in my project, I added the following lines in my JS file:

```
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'); 
require('bootstrap-markdown/js/bootstrap-markdown.js')
```

The plugin can be initialised using data-attributes and this works fine, but when extra listeners needs to be coded in you need to initialise it using `$(element).markdown()`.

When I do this however, it gives the error that:

> markdown() is not a function.

Is there anything else that needs to be added in when using a package like this?

Link to package page: [bootstrap-markdown](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything else that needs to be added in when using a package
>   like this?

Yes, it also needs **jquery**; See [source code](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown/blob/604a3be21a0f05b2c3388b3199e23666e41be24f/js/bootstrap-markdown.js#L25).

**Installation**:

```
npm install bootstrap-markdown jquery --save
```

**Usage**:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-markdown/js/bootstrap-markdown.js');

$(function() {
  $(element).markdown();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, jquery is added, did not mention it in the post, will edit to add that info, but it still says .markdown is not a function